# App wide accessible and changeable variable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i have a navbar that checks if a variable is true or false to open/close, i will call it **"navcontrol"**.
I have a component for my navbar and a different component for each page.

My app.component.html :

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem is, a button change the navcontrol, this button is on the **"app-navbar"** . Each page also needs to change the padding according to the value of navcontrol, they move to the bottom.

So i have a listener `[class.opened]="navcontrol === true"` on each page, adding a opened class that does the padding with css.

On a angular doc i saw that i could `ng generate service navbarcontrol` then use like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class NavbarcontrolService {

  static navcontrol: boolean;
  constructor()
  {
      console.log(NavbarcontrolService.navcontrol)
  }
}
```

Then my navbar.component.ts and page1.component.ts :

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  navcontrol = NavbarcontrolService.navcontrol;
```

Then on my page1 html:

```
<div class="content " [class.toggled]="navcontrol=== true">
```

My navbar html, where the button that changes navcontrol is:

```
<button type="button" class="button"
          [class.isopen]="navcontrol=== true"
          [class.isclosed]="navcontrol=== false"
          (click)="navcontrol= !navcontrol">
</button>
```

When i click on the button inside my **"app-navbar"** it chages the local navcontrol variable, the text from **"app-page1"** doesn't receive the change, so they are referencing to different variables, not a single global variable.
How could i declare a global **"navcontrol"** that if i change it on my **"app-navbar"** my **"app-page1"** will also be checking the same variable and see that it has changed?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is with a BehaviorSubject in a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the global variable with property getters and setters in your components. This technique will make sure that all the calls to the `navcontrol` properties will ultimately refer to the same global variable.

```
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private navbarcontrolService: NavbarcontrolService) { }

  get navcontrol(): boolean {
    return this.navbarcontrolService.navcontrol;
  }

  set navcontrol(value: boolean) {
    this.navbarcontrolService.navcontrol = value;
  }

  ...
}
```

with the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class NavbarcontrolService {
  navcontrol: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I changed each component.ts to what you wrote but it didn't worked. Also tried to add "return" that seems to be missed, but didn't worked eater

Comment: So whats the best way to do what i want?

Comment: Sorry. I just made a correction to the setter in my answer. I had forgotten `= value`. Please note that some components may need only the `get` or only the `set`.

Comment: Its not working very well. My app-page1 is not receiving the changes from the variable. On navcontrol service i need to declare my variabel as `static navcontrol: boolean;` right?

Comment: If you inject the service in the components, you can access the variable of the service instance. The variable doesn't need to be `static` when used that way. I updated the answer to show that (see the injection in the component class constructor).

Comment: Its working now, thanks very much =) Is there any documentation where i can check more about this? understand it better

Comment: Yes, services are well documented in Angular documentation, for example in [this page](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4). There are many other references about Angular services, like [this one](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/beginners-guide-to-angular-4-services--cms-29675). Typescript property getters and setters are explained in [this documentation page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: Don't forget to mark/upvote if this answer helped you. :-)

Comment: Sure,  i'm sorry, i always do it, just forgot now